# Memory issues in iPad application

Tags: ipad

I have created one iPad application. I have tested the application in simulator. I did not get any error message and it didn't crash.
But when i try to test with iPad device, I am getting below error messages;

```
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-18635-67
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 3591.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 3591.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.
```

I have restarted my iPad device, but no use. I am getting same issues.

Please help me to resolve it.

Why I am getting this error message.

Comment: Sometimes you also have to restart your development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting your iPad or at least unplugging it from your Mac. I've seen this issue when terminating a debug while it is still installing on the device.

Answer (score 1):

As for the error messages, i am not sure what they mean but it doesn't appear to be a memory issue. I could be wrong.

Just a side note, running an app on the simulator means diddly squat for running it on a device. The device has way more limitations in memory and the simulators interface(mouse) is far from the same as the touch screen.

So just a heads up, if you have a device available, always test and debug on the device.